# BringSubViewToFront Repositions UIView in AutoLayout

Tags: objective-c, swift

With Autolayout, the UIView resets whenever `bringSubviewToFront` is called.

I tried setting an original position with `txtViewPosition`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if txtViewPosition != nil { // original position
        txtView.frame = txtViewPosition!
    }
}
```

It looks like the view is the correct position, but it is still showing up in its original spot (set in AutoLayout).

Comment: What do you mean with "the UIView resets"? Are you explicitly setting the frame somewhere? If you use AutoLayout, you shouldn't mess with the `frame` property. You should update the constraints and let the layout engine figure out the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Since autoLayout the way to move views change.
Don't forgot your constraints.
Better than updating directly your frames you should update constraints.
iOS will always update your views to satisfying constraints.
So You can make an IBOutlet of one of your constraints and update it in code.