# UIView Get and Set Constraints Programatically

Tags: objective-c, swift

How can I get current constraints and set them later for a UIView. Am I doing this correctly?

### Current Attempt:

**Get Current Constraints**

```
 // get current constraints
 var txtViewConstraints = txtView.constraints()
```

**Set Constraints Later**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if txtViewConstraints.isEmpty == false {
        txtView.addConstraints(txtViewConstraints)
    }
}
```

Edit: This is a followup to this question: [BringSubViewToFront Repositions UIView in AutoLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29064016/bringsubviewtofront-repositions-uiview-in-autolayout)

#### Update Code Used to Move txtView:

```
@IBAction func moveTxtView(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        var translation: CGPoint =  sender.translationInView(self.view)
        sender.view?.center = CGPointMake(sender.view!.center.x +  translation.x, sender.view!.center.y + translation.y)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPointMake(0, 0), inView: self.view)
        
        txtViewConstraints = txtView.constraints()
        txtViewPosition = CGRect(x: txtView.frame.origin.x, y: txtView.frame.origin.y, width: txtView.frame.size.width, height: txtView.frame.size.height)
    }
```

Comment: By `viewConstraints` on above do you mean `txtViewConstarints`? What is the problem you have, trouble storing constraints in a variable or adding them to the view?

Comment: Sorry, updated. Typo while writing the question. The problem is the constraints are not being updated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're attempting to do with this, but have you checked that it's not just because txtViewConstraints actually is empty?

Comment: in relation to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29064016/bringsubviewtofront-repositions-uiview-in-autolayout

Comment: What is the problem? What result does your current attempt give?

Comment: @rdelmar it doesn't set the restraints. the view bounces back to its original position.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that. Are you removing constraints, then at some point later, you add back the same ones? -- it should go back to its original position if that's what you're doing. It would be helpful to know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @rdelmar I'm updating the existing constraints. The user can move the `txtView` around. But when the user adds a new view (such as a sticker, or another textView), the original `txtView` pops back to the original position. I tried setting both the frame and constraint of the `txtView` after the user moves and it tried updating the constraints in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to ensure it stays in the same place. But it continues to pop back to the original position.

Comment: Did you try moving it by modifying the constraints only? You should not set any frames when you're using auto layout. If you do, the view will move back to the position defined by its constraints when the view needs to redraw itself. You should post the code you're using to move txtView.

Comment: As I said, you can't set frames when you're using auto layout, so that's the problem. You either need to not use auto layout for txtView (by adding it in code), in which case your current code will probably work, or you can modify the constant parameter of the constraints to move your view.

Comment: @rdelmar am I not currently setting the constraints?

Comment: I'm not sure what constraints you have in txtView.constraints(), but in any case, you're also setting fames which you must not do! The constraints that set the position of txtView should belong to its superview, so I don't think that txtView.constraints() will have any constraints that would be useful to position txtView anyway.